# Change font of subcaptions using memoir

Tags: captions, memoir

The `memoir` class has built-in macros for styling the font of captions, including both the caption itself and the prefix (i.e. "Figure 1"), with `\captiontitlefont{}` and `\captionnamefont{}`.

The class also has built-in subcaption capabilities, removing the need for the `caption` package ([TeX will yell at you](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116807/i-get-an-error-when-using-subfigure-with-memoir) if you try to use `memoir` and `caption` at the same time).

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to change the font for subcaptions in `memoir`—there's no `\subcaptiontitlefont{}`.

For example, this MWE…

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

% Enable \subtop and \subbottom in figures
\newsubfloat{figure}

% Change caption fonts
\captiontitlefont{\scriptsize\sffamily}
\captionnamefont{\scriptsize\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subtop[Thing 1]{\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{}}\\
  \subbottom[Thing 2]{\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{}}\\
  \caption{Two subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

…creates this, with a sans serif main caption and seriffed subcaptions:

[image: MWE result]

There are ways to use the `caption` package regardless of `memoir`'s warning ([such as this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48565/11851)), overriding `memoir`'s built-in caption styling settings like so:

```
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={sf,scriptsize},textfont={sf,scriptsize}}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont={sf,scriptsize},textfont={sf,scriptsize}}
```

However, this still does not style the subfloat captions correctly (and it overwrites all of `memoir`'s caption defaults).

What's the best/correct way to set the font for `memoir`-supported subcaptions?

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, never mind. There *is* a built-in `memoir` way—it just doesn't follow the same naming conventions as `\captiontitlefont` so it was trickier to find in the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf). Subcaptions are controlled by three macros, with the following defaults:

```
\subcaptionsize{\footnotesize}
\subcaptionlabelfont{\normalfont}
\subcaptionfont{\normalfont}
```

So this example…

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

% Enable \subtop and \subbottom in figures
\newsubfloat{figure}

% Change caption fonts
\captiontitlefont{\scriptsize\sffamily}
\captionnamefont{\scriptsize\sffamily}

\subcaptionsize{\scriptsize}
\subcaptionlabelfont{\sffamily}
\subcaptionfont{\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subtop[Thing 1]{\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{}}\\
  \subbottom[Thing 2]{\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{}}\\
  \caption{Two subfigures}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

… now yields this correctly styled output:

[image: Correct output]